# Download pdf file (response type blob),post method in react native

Tags: react-native

Am giving here body type as its showing error response timed out error

{"obj":{"empcode":"RV0001","month":"January","year":"2019"},
    "filename":"pdf/RV0001January2019.pdf"
} response type blob ,

my code is like this

actualDownload = () => {
    this.setState({
      progress: 0,
      loading: true
    });
    let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    RNFetchBlob.config({

```
  timeout: 60000,
  path: dirs.DownloadDir + "/path.pdf",
  fileCache: true
})
  .fetch(
    "POST",
    "http://202.21.34.152:9090/pdfLink/download",

     {
    body: JSON.stringify({
      obj:{empcode:"RV0001",month:"January",year:"2019"},
 filename:"pdf/RV0001January2019.pdf",
  }),
}       

  )
  .progress((received, total) => {
    console.log("progress", received / total);
    this.setState({ progress: received / total });
  })
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      progress: 100,
      loading: false
    });
    ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
      "Your file has been downloaded to downloads folder!",
      ToastAndroid.SHORT,
      ToastAndroid.BOTTOM
    );
  });
```

};

Comment: You can change const { dirs } = RNFetchBlob.fs; with yours. Then check your body. If you get timeout error, it means you can't reach to server.

Comment: I removed it and i checked again its getting status code 16  ,download unsuccessfull,help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Please try to call api with this body usign Postman. First of all you must sure that you can get response from server.

Comment: yes i had tried it its getting response from that i have to save the response from post man.